# saving a beautifulsoup web scrape to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

python noob here, I have managed to scrape a list of companies from Wikipedia, how do I save the output as a JSON file?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import JSON

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_traded_on_the_JSE"
responce = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll('table', {'class':"wikitable sortable"})

for table in soup.find_all('table', {'class':"wikitable sortable"}):
         print(table.text
```

Comment: You should be using `import json` and not `JSON`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_traded_on_the_JSE"
responce = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(responce.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.findAll('table', {'class':"wikitable sortable"})
tables = [str(x.text) for x in table]
json_text = json.dumps(tables)

with open('companies.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_text)
```

That should do the trick. Although I'm not sure what you're going to do with it, since that's a list of all the data in the table.

Comment: Thank you very much! What im actually trying to do is save the data in a CSV file with headings for the rows, how do I go about doing that? Thank you again.

Comment: filename = 'jse.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f: 
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['company','Symbol','url','lines']) 
    w.writeheader() 
    for table in tables: 
        w.writerow(table) something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In *table* you will retrieve all the object you are interrested in, you can even add more granularity in your selection to only fetch the names from the HTML.
Then do:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(table, outfile)
```